# Error 2753 with AllowDowngrades="yes" in WiX installer

Tags: wix

I've got an WiX installer with AllowDowngrades="yes" in MajorUpdate.

If I install version 2, then install version 1, I'm getting an error 2753 and the files are not copied (I get an entry in Add / Remove programs for version 1 though).

FYI, the file to be installed has got the same version as the installer.
Also, note that launching installer 1 again works fine on second attempt.

Any idea?

Note: GUIDs are set as follow:

```
<Product Id="*" ... Version="!(bind.FileVersion.Launcher)" ... UpgradeCode="42076B77-741F-4B80-BA43-E8721DE0E4AD">
        <Package Id='*' ... />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error was because the files to copy had older versions than the ones installed when downgrading.

I solved this by setting the [REINSTALLMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to "dmus" in order to overwrite files with different version when reinstalling (all credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544990/wix-major-upgrade-doesnt-completely-install-app-on-downgrade/1585925#1585925)):

```
<Wix ...>
  <Product ...>
    <Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="dmus" />
```